# How to read an array from PHP in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have the following php code:

```
$response["information"]   = mysql_fetch_array($result) ;                   
echo json_encode($response);
```

Where my php sentence only returns and array. And what I want to do is to read the elements of that array in android, so I have wrote the following code, but seems not working:

```
Date_Queries date_info_query = new Date_Queries();
            json = date_info_query.getDateInformation(uid_request,is_your_request);

            if (json.getString("result_code") != null) { 

                // Result Code = 0 --> Succesfully Select
                if (json.getString("result_code").equals("0")){ 

                    JSONArray information = json.getJSONArray("information");
                    JSONObject jobj = information.getJSONObject(0);

                    status       = jobj.getString("status");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of knowing what is wrong with your code, as we don't have the full picture. The fragments you have offered leave us with a partial picture. That said, here is how we can help:

1.) Show us what makes up the Date_Queries() object. How is it making the request? Etc.

2.) Show us the structure of the $response object.

**3.) Print the Java request result to the console before attempting to parse it. Verify it's correct.**

4.) Surround your Java in try/catch and print a stack trace so you can better evaluate any kind of errors.

5.) Show us where you are setting result_code, and any other possible responses

6.) Show us all relevant code

7.) Show us all relevant code

8.) Side note, you should use single quotes in php, ALWAYS, unless you know what you are doing... `$response['information'] = ...`

EDIT:

---

According to your comment below, the issue you are having is that you are treating your response as an Array, instead of an Object... Please read the JSON spec:

http://www.json.org/

Array: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
Object: { "key1":"val1", "key2":"val2" }

If you treat your base object as an object instead, it should stop throwing the exception it is currently throwing.

You can use a parameter of `json_encode()` to ensure that all responses in arrays are converted to objects. The keys will be the array indices.

`json_encode($ob,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

---

If the problem isn't with the outermost type of the response, check to ensure that other parts of it, such as "information", are in fact correct. For instance, `mysql_fetch_array` can return FALSE, which means it is not an array by the time it hits your Android app:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

---

Final note, you should stop using the mysql_* functions, and use PDOs instead.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: The message what I am getting is : org.json.JSONException: Value {"uid":"369",:"2","sex":"1","19":"","17":"","lastname":"Doe","deny_observations":"","18":"","deny_option":"","15":"12","16":"P","13":"","14":"2013-10-14 09:39:57","11":"14\/10\/2013","observations":"","12":"09:40","21":"","timestamp":"2013-08-28 00:47:32",ormation of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray.

Comment: In php I return an array of strings, and what I want to do is to show the values of every element of that array in a toast in Android.